# Will an index on a uuid column be smaller in Postgres than MySQL / InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, uuid

I've got a MySQL database which uses UUID (v4) as identifier for all entities. The UUID's are stored as a `CHAR(36)` and `ascii` charset.

For one table with about 50.000.000 rows, the index on the UUID columns takes up about 5.5GB.

It is my understanding that Postgres handles UUID's better (performance wise) than MySQL / InnoDB because of the builtin `uuid` data type in Postgres.

Does Postgres store UUIDs in a more optimized way than MySQL, and should I expect the UUID index to take up less space than it does in MySQL / InnoDB?

Comment: *The UUID's are stored as a CHAR(36) and ascii charset.* Why? In MySQL you may store it as BINARY(16) using [BIN_TO_UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid) and UU_D_TO_BIN().

Comment: From the other side I doubt that you'll see the difference in disk space consumption - the difference is 20 bytes only, and the amount of records per block will stay the same or as a maximum it will increase by 1 which won't effect the table body disk file size in practice.

Comment: @Akina I'm using BINARY(16) in other databases, but for this case it's simply not practical. It would require too much work converting all primary keys of that database to BINARY(16). Also, for readability and usability when doing queries I find that it clutters things when I have to do UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID everywhere.

Comment: "*it's simply not practical. It would require too much work converting all primary keys of that database to BINARY(16)*" - But it would be less work and more practical to completely migrate your database to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @J.D. yes, I belive so. The application is based on an ORM (Hibernate), so it does not have much tailor made SQL. I suspect fewer obstacles for migrating than the massive amount of work required to rewrite queries.

Comment: @sbrattla I think you're underestimating the amount of work required to migrate database systems. That's fine that your interface between the application layer and your database layer is an ORM (which makes it just as easy to change data types in your database layer then). But you're still going to have to migrate all of your Tables (and other database objects), queries, and probably re-write some of the queries (since the syntax isn't 100% the same between both database systems). And then your primary keys data types still need to be changed anyway, just as if you did it in your current DB.

Comment: Is this a secondary index or the PRIMARY KEY?  If secondary, InnoDB also stores the column(s) of the PK in the index's BTree.  Does Postgres do the same thing?

Comment: 50M rows accessed by UUID -- I hope you have lots of buffer_pool.  The accesses are very random.  If on thy other hand, you used `UUID_TO_BIN()`, you could get temporal clustering.

Comment: Frameworks tend to work well for toy projects, not for 50M-row projects.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

> should I expect the UUID index to take up less space than it does in MySQL / InnoDB?

Most certainly yes. It's simple math: `char(36)` takes up 36 bytes to store a UUID.

Postgres' `uuid` type is stored in 16 bytes, so storing that in an index saves 20 bytes per entry (ignoring alignment). 20 bytes times 50 million is a bit under 1 GB.

I would also assume that comparing `uuid` values is faster than comparing `char(36)` values.

---

Edit:

An index on 50 million UUIDs seems to take only 1.5 GB in Postgres:

```
create table the_table (id uuid);
insert into the_table
select gen_random_uuid()
from generate_series(1,50e6);

create index ix_uid on the_table(id);

select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('ix_uid'))
```

The above yields `1504 MB` using Postgres 15 (Windows 10)

So apparently there is more optimization involved than "just" the 20 bytes per row.

Comment: I'd use a `varbinary` on MySQL, which should result in a roughly similar index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe for my particular case, going from char to binary would require a lot of application logic to be changed to convert back and forth to binary. The reason I'm looking at Postgres is that it has the uuid data type, and the move from MySQL to Postgres would require few application changes.

Comment: @sbrattla: I just did a simple test and created an index on 50 million UUIDs - the index size is 1.5GB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank's for doing an actual test!

Comment: You does not take into account the granularity. For example, if average row size is 1 kb and block size is 16 kb then the block may contain up to 14 records. If the row size decreases by 20 bytes then the amount of records per block won't change..

Comment: @Akina: the "row size" for a single column index is always the same regardless of the size of the table - it's the size of that column. The question is about the size of the index, not the size of the table. The size of the table might be smaller as well, but that is more complicated to measure because of the other columns (padding) as you correctly point out.

Comment: Oops... I loose that the question asks about the index.. sorry. For an index - in MySQL the index by an expression `(UUID_TO_BIN(column))` may be created. Or by generated column with this expression. In last option the column may be virtual, and it does not occupy the space in the table body.

Comment: @Akina I assume an expression index on UUID_TO_BIN(column) will be a secondary index, and not reduce the overall size of indexes.

Comment: @sbrattla You ask about the size of separate secondary index, is it? if so then the size of the index by textual UUID is ~twice while comparing with the index by the above expression. I.e. replacing the index by immediate value with the index by an expression will decrease total disk size occupied by the index.

Comment: MariaDB 10.7 also has a UUID datatype with builtin conversion.

Comment: "more optimization involved than "just" the 20 bytes" - InnoDB has a lot of overhead in its BTrees.  2x-3x is a useful Rule of Thumb.

Comment: Keep in mind that you pay 20 bytes for _every_ index that includes it.  In InnoDB, if the `PRIMARY KEY` is a UUID, then _every_ secondary index has the same 20-byte cost.